# WolframAlpha::kbserr: Request to knowledgebase server api.wolframalpha.com failed with error code 503

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

It is all in the title. If I run `WolframAlpha["2+2"]`, Mathematica returns the error `WolframAlpha::kbserr: Request to knowledgebase server api.wolframalpha.com failed with error code 503.` What is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the servers were down, and are back up again. It would have been nice to have a more descriptive error though.